# SQL query: How to get all employee from the given SQL query

Tags: sql-server

I have the following query and i want all the employee present in the table...how to do that???

This is my table:

[image: This is my table]

```
SELECT E.EmployeeId  --assuming ID is the PK of Employee (E)
     , tb1.monthDate
     , ISNULL(present, 0 ) as present 
     , ISNULL(expected, 0 ) as expected
     , ISNULL(late, 0 ) as late 
FROM (SELECT distinct EmployeeId  
      FROM tblAttendanceDetails) E
LEFT JOIN (SELECT EmployeeId as id,count(Logintime) as present, month(Logintime) as monthDate 
           FROM tblAttendanceDetails 
           WHERE cast(Logintime as time)< cast('09:20' as time)  
           GROUP BY  EmployeeId,month(Logintime)) as tb1
  on E.EmployeeId = tb1.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT EmployeeId,count(Logintime) as late, month(Logintime) as monthDate2 
           FROM tblAttendanceDetails 
           WHERE cast(Logintime as time)> cast('09:30' as time)  
           GROUP BY EmployeeId, month(Logintime)) as tb2 
  on E.EmployeeId=tb2.EmployeeId 
 and tb1.monthDate=tb2.monthDate2
LEFT JOIN (SELECT EmployeeId,count(Logintime) as expected,month(Logintime) as monthDate3 
           FROM tblAttendanceDetails 
           WHERE cast(Logintime as time) between cast('09:20' as time) and cast('09:30' as time)  
           GROUP BY EmployeeId,month(Logintime)) as tb3 
  on E.EmployeeId=tb3.EmployeeId 
 and tb1.monthDate=tb3.monthDate3
```

this is my query result:
[image: this is my query result:]

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. You are going to need to provide us some actual details so we can help. Sending links to images is not going to result in anybody being able to help. And please don't be scared to add some formatting and white space to your queries so they are not a wall of text. Here is a great place to start improving your question. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: You should re-edit your answer and use images.. it's next to {} in toolbar... That way people can see both alongside each other. Furthermore, something posted with a link to http://rextester.com/l/sql_server_online_compiler would be an order of magnitude better again

Comment: Your first table in your from clause should be the employee table and left join all other tables to it.  Since you may have an employee w/o any attendance details, you need a source table which contains all employees.  In addition the where clause on the sub queries limit those employees not having a date in the requested period; thus you need a source for all employees.

Comment: @xQbert Perhaps you mean that i must add a new select statement which takes all employees from tblEmployee just before the statement which contains where clause??

Comment: @sum-it no.  `FROM employee E LEFT JOIN tbl1... LEFT JOIN tbl2... LEFT JOIN tbl3` and I would have each join tie back not to tbl1 but to E and keep the and for the months the same back to tb1

Comment: I am assuming tblAttendanceDetails is causing filtering. Could be helpful to see that table too..

Comment: So if you output tb1, tb2 and tb3 as temp tables first, with select into syntax, then did left joins on them to original it would work. xQberts solution does this by naming table E first.

Comment: @JGFMK https://i.stack.imgur.com/AldFM.png][1] this is my tblAttendanceDetails table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I envision something like this...  in this way the filtering done in the subqueries has no impact on all the records from employee.

```
SELECT E.id  --assuming ID is the PK of Employee (E)
     , tb1.monthDate
     , coalesce(present, 0 ) as present 
     , coalesce(expected, 0 ) as expected
     , coalesce(late, 0 ) as late 
FROM Employee E
LEFT JOIN (SELECT EmployeeId as id,count(Logintime) as present, month(Logintime) as monthDate 
           FROM tblAttendanceDetails 
           WHERE cast(Logintime as time)< cast('09:20' as time)  
           GROUP BY  EmployeeId,month(Logintime)) as tb1
  on E.ID = tb1.ID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT EmployeeId,count(Logintime) as late, month(Logintime) as monthDate2 
           FROM tblAttendanceDetails 
           WHERE cast(Logintime as time)> cast('09:30' as time)  
           GROUP BY EmployeeId, month(Logintime)) as tb2 
  on E.id=tb2.EmployeeId 
 and tb1.monthDate=tb2.monthDate2
LEFT JOIN (SELECT EmployeeId,count(Logintime) as expected,month(Logintime) as monthDate3 
           FROM tblAttendanceDetails 
           WHERE cast(Logintime as time) between cast('09:20' as time) and cast('09:30' as time)  
           GROUP BY EmployeeId,month(Logintime)) as tb3 
  on E.id=tb3.EmployeeId 
 and tb1.monthDate=tb3.monthDate3
```

Maybe you mean:

```
SELECT E.id  --assuming ID is the PK of Employee (E)
     , E.monthDate
     , coalesce(present, 0 ) as present 
     , coalesce(expected, 0 ) as expected
     , coalesce(late, 0 ) as late 
FROM (SELECT distinct EmployeeID ID, month(Logintime) as monthdate
      FROM tblAttendanceDetails) E
LEFT JOIN (SELECT EmployeeId as id,count(Logintime) as present, month(Logintime) as monthDate 
           FROM tblAttendanceDetails 
           WHERE cast(Logintime as time)< cast('09:20' as time)  
           GROUP BY  EmployeeId,month(Logintime)) as tb1
  on E.ID = tb1.ID
 and E.Monthdate = t1.monthdate
LEFT JOIN (SELECT EmployeeId,count(Logintime) as late, month(Logintime) as monthDate2 
           FROM tblAttendanceDetails 
           WHERE cast(Logintime as time)> cast('09:30' as time)  
           GROUP BY EmployeeId, month(Logintime)) as tb2 
  on E.id=tb2.EmployeeId 
 and E.monthDate=tb2.monthDate2
LEFT JOIN (SELECT EmployeeId,count(Logintime) as expected,month(Logintime) as monthDate3 
           FROM tblAttendanceDetails 
           WHERE cast(Logintime as time) between cast('09:20' as time) and cast('09:30' as time)  
           GROUP BY EmployeeId,month(Logintime)) as tb3 
  on E.id=tb3.EmployeeId 
 and E.monthDate=tb3.monthDate3
```

Or perhaps we can eliminate the joins and subqueries using window functions.

```
SELECT EmployeeID as ID 
     , month(Logintime) as MonthDate
     , sum(case when cast(Logintime as time) < cast('09:20' as time) 
                then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by month(Logintime),employeeID) as present 
     , sum(case when cast(Logintime as time)> cast('09:30' as time)
                then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by month(Logintime),employeeID)  as expected
     , sum(case when cast(Logintime as time) between cast('09:20' as time) and cast('09:30' as time)
                then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by month(Logintime),employeeID)  as late 
FROM tblAttendanceDetails E
--GROUP BY EmployeeID, month(LoginTime) -- is the group by needed don't think so since we're using the window functions and the case abstracts the logintime to 1/0 that is now summed...but not sure w/o testing.
```

Nope (with regards to SQL comment about needing the group by) based on: [MSFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql)

Comment: sorry for the confusion but the image i have given is the image of tblattendanceDetails and there is another table tblEmployee which contains all the employee

Comment: Right.  I'm saying you have to use the employee table if you want ALL employees as an employee may not have any details at the time of the query; and since you said you wanted all employees you needed a data set which contains all employees.... I'm missing something obviously though...

Comment: ok... when you say: "all the employee present in the table" do you mean the tblAttendanceDetails?  If so just substitute my employee for `(Select distinct ID from tblAttendanceDetails) E`

Comment: easy enough coalesce all columns to 0.  odd ... I though isnull would handle that ...

Comment: didn't get you...still the same result

Comment: still the same result

Comment: Ok that means that those employees don't have a login time before 9:20  maybe we need to add monthdate to our subquery and join to it... 1 sec.

Comment: Added monhtdate to E subquery and modified all other joins to join back to E.Month date.  Now shouldn't have nulls as the date will always be populated IF that employee has detail for that month.  when I looked at the null I misread it thinking it was columns 3-5 not col 2.

Comment: Might be able to eliminate all the subqueries using window functions and a case statement...

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: I've added a 3rd possibility I can't test it (id need sample data) so you would need to compare this if it runs to the other results to ensure accuracy.  it uses conditional aggregation and sum instead of count to get your totals.  I had to tweek it a bit to get the month and Id correct again since my original comment.